# container-fluid with container inside in only one node in Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

It's possible to accomplish this with Twitter Bootstrap:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- FULL BACKGROUND -->
    <div class="container">
        <!-- CONTENT CENTERED -->
    </div>
</div>
```

But with only 1 div?

```
<div class="container-semifluid">
    <!-- CONTENT CENTERED WITH FULL BACKGROUND -->
</div>
```

The objective is to have a fluid background and center the content as if it was a "container". I have the 1 div restriction.

Comment: I doubt that. Since the normal `.container` has a fixed width, I can't think of a way to give the same div a fullscreen fluid background. Is wrapping the fluid div around the normal one via javascript an option for you? It's an interesting question, I'm curious if someone else has another solution..

Comment: @Sebsemillia only css, I'm curious too, maybe with a % left-right padding...

Comment: Yes, that is of course possible. But that doesn't correspond to the normal bootstrap `.container` class. If you want to use a % left-right padding, just go with the `.container-fluid` and alter the percentage of the padding.. http://www.bootply.com/xAI1m0QO4j